# Parse.com relation add extra field? (android)

Tags: android, parse-platform, relation

I wonder if its possible to add an extra field when adding the object to user relation. 
For example, lets say I have a person trying to add a list of bars he like in to his user-object relation. But I would like to allow the user to put his/her personal note on each bar, is it possible to add a field in the user-object relation query in parse.com?

note: i know how to add the object to user relation, but I can't find a way to add extra field to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add extra data to a relation. Think of it as just a many-to-many relation. If you want to add comment data to each "like" you'll need to create a new "Likes" class with the fields:

```
User - pointer
Bar - pointer
Comment - String
```